# Selecting Time period with multiplexer

Tags: digital-logic, analog, circuit-design, vlsi

Varying input signal I want to select delay line based on the time period of input and tap out the output of delay line to input to Multiplexer.
For Example: Input Time period 1ns the input to Mux from delay line 1 should be selected and for input time period 2ns delay line 2 should be selected to input of Mux.

How can I control the output of Mux from the input from delay based on different input signals?

[image]

Comment: What does the datasheet of your mux say about how it is controlled by its inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas (I liked idea 2 and 3 better, since they are easier to do digitally):

1. You can have a local oscillator with something near a 250-500MHz signal and a PLL. Then you put a comparator in the phase output. Calibrate the comparator to the exact frequency difference you want. The comparator output will be the mux input (maybe inverted, depending on mux type, but you can always invert the comparator inputs).
2. Use a Monostable multivibrator. Trigger it with the input pulse. Tune it to return at something like 1.5ns. When it returns, if the input is still up, it is slower than 1.5ns. If it is already down, it is faster. Use the vibrator return as trigger to a logic comparator, making the output of this logic the input to the mux.
3. Use a faster-than-input counter. When the input pulse starts, start the counter. When the pulse finishes, stop the counter and use its result in a comparator. If it counted more than n times (counter frequency-dependant), then you should switch the mux. Use either the A>B or A<B outputs from the comparator as the mux input. Don't forget to latch the counter before the comparator (use input as triggers) to avoid hazards while counting.